# odoo 8 selection field self always empty

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have to create a selection field based on other column. i mean the data comes from other table but based on current table column value. so i created a selection field as below:

```
pull_location = fields.Selection(selection='_get_pull_locations',string='Pull Location')
```

and the function is as below:

```
@api.multi
def _get_pull_locations(self):
    data=[]
    ** Get the values from other table based on current record ** 
    return [('value1', 'String 1'), ('value2', 'String 2')]
```

Always when i debug i get self as empty class object ( stock.test()). the scenario is i have a column named zone in stock.test, i have another table called stock.location, so for current record i check the stock.location table where column pull_zone == zone of stock.test and if yes append the selection (pull_location) with that values.
But always the object is empty. 
I tried @api.one, @api.multi, @api.model , Nothing happens.

Please help.
Thanks,

Comment: Check the accepted answer https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/how-to-create-dynamic-selection-field-fields-selection-99421

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with following:

```
@api.multi
def _get_pull_locations(self):
    ** Get the values from other table based on current record ** 
    return [
        ('value1', 'String 1'), 
        ('value2', 'String 2')
    ]

pull_location = fields.Selection('_get_pull_locations', string='Pull Location')
```

Afterwards, Restart Odoo server and upgrade your module.

Comment: Hi odedra, the self object is still empty. i want to get records in the self object